# Suggestions for Storing large collection of related words

Tags: javascript, database

I am trying to create a simple sentence generator that uses templates and a database of words. It will be a website where essentially a user could click a button to generate a sentence.

For example: The {animal} is on top of the {large_obj}.
would choose a item from animals and then choose another item from the list that it points to. And it would also choose a large_obj.
A possible outcome would be: The chicken is on top of the house.

[image: data relation]

I am looking for suggestions for how to store the data.
I was thinking either a database with tables for each collection or a large JSON object. But I don't have enough experience to feel good about either decision.

It is currently planned to use Node.js with a Postgres database.
I'm hoping to have 1000-2000 words total.

Comment: How many words are going to be stored in your word groups (e.g., Large_objs)? How do you account for the word de-referencing of animals to another word group?

Comment: Im hoping to have 1000-2000 words total. By de-referencing to you mean going up the tree from animals back to nouns? If so, that is not something that I will need to do.

Comment: Your example shows an animal, but you then have to decide which animal type in order to decide the specific animal. How do you get from **{animal}** to **chicken** ?

Comment: Oh I see your question. Birds would be randomly chosen from Animals and then chicken would be randomly chosen from Birds

Comment: See [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/102937)

Comment: It would be much simpler to just combine all of the possible animals into a single storage/table.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman but what if instead I did: The {mammal} is on top of the {large_obj}. I dont want to lose the specificity

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you I will be looking over those

Comment: Is this going to be a command line/desktop app or something that will run as a web server/service?

Comment: It will be a website where essentially a user could click a button to generate a sentence.

Comment: I just did a Google search with "ontology" and "sentence generator" and this paper is returned as a hit. Just for reference only. I am not familiar with this area. 
http://www.aueb.gr/users/ion/docs/naturalowl_eacl2009.pdf